# The correct Syntax for checking the keys in the hashmap inside ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, hashmap, test-suite

This works for me, however I know that it is incorrect to use a parameter Raw type, so how am I supposed to do this correctly? The end goal is to check each key for correctness in a test suite.

I have other ideas but I want to learn the correct way to do this rather than guess.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> results = dbConn.getDataFromTable("select * from paf_extract_in.hcr_retro_chart_list WHERE payer = 'HEALTHTEAMADVANTAGE'");

for (HashMap result: results) {
     if (!result.containsKey("hcr_retro_chart_list.packetid")) {
         Assertions.fail();
     }

}
```

I can do this as well, however this feels wrong and I can not do any other Assertions on the items.

```
for (Object result: results) {    
    if (!result.toString().contains("hcr_retro_chart_list.packetid")) {
        Assertions.fail();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with copying the relevant part of the generic type one line above?

Comment: What about `for(HashMap<String,Object> result : results)` ?

Comment: @azro why does that not complain but just HashMap does? I am coming back to java from an extended time with python so I am struggling to remember these things...

Comment: is "that" the object version ? Because Object is not a parametrized class, HashMap is